# Unhandled promise rejection when trying to run docker for a mongoose/express/mongodb application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I am creating an application using express, mongoose, and mongodb. It works perfectly fine when I run the commands npm run start:dev but I am running into issues with dockerizing it. I am running docker build -t store:1.0.0 . and docker run -p 3000:3000 store:1.0.0

The application begins to run in docker, but when I check postman to view all of the items within my db I get this error unhandled promise rejection warning.

The error I get is: (node:43) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

```
DockerFile: 

FROM node:14 

WORKDIR /store

COPY .npmrc package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

CMD ["npm","run","start:dev"]

JS:

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/storedb',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true, useCreateIndex:true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use localhost:27017 the api looks on your container local network, use your local ip instead, 192.168.x.xx:27017 you can watch it using **ipconfig** command con windows or **ifconfig** command on Linux.

This happens because your mongo server is active on your pc, not on the container network.